# Parsing binary file to Idb faster with Ida

Tags: ida, idapython

When Ida parsing big file(50 MB) its can take few hours to parse binary file to IDB even with Intel I9 CPU, Maybe Ida doesn't use all cores?

Is there any way to make that process faster? run it on all over cores?

Maybe if I need to parse to idb only functiond that contains specific string ,can I do that insread of parsing all binary to Idb?

Comment: The initial "autoanalysis" is a as far as I remember a linear process that only uses one core. To make that process faster use a CPU with less cores and a higher turbo frequency.

Comment: @Robert. That the PC I have. Can I configer so.ething in IDA or run it via cmd with another configuration the makes it faster?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to simply speed-up IDA analysis. Ida has some configuration files that can limit certain analyses, however this would also reduce analysis result. And this may not have a large effect on your binary. Therefore the best option is just to wait or in case you want to analyze multiple binaries open them at the same time in multiple IDA instances.